# Raspberry Pi resetting across reboots

Tags: raspbian, config.txt, reset

My RPi 3 seems to have run into a strange problem. Everytime I reboot it, it seems to reset all my settings, namely Keyboard layout and taskbar icons some other setting as well.

Also if after a reboot I access the config.txt file through my laptop (running Kali), I find that its completely blank.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Some SD cards have a read-only failsafe mode.

- Backup your SD card with Win32DiskImager. (**In case i am in the wrong !**)
- Format it.
- Eject and re-insert.
- The data should "magically" re-appear.

Throw your card away. Perhaps you can get it replaced under warranty ?

Comment: It came with a starter kit I bought for the RPi, 16GB with noobs preinstalled... Yesternight I complied OpenCV libraries on my RPi and that was something I would not like to do again.. So if there are any solutions which don't need me to format my SD card, I'd be glad to follow them

Comment: @YaddyVirus - You can make a backup with `dd`

Comment: Umm any solutions which do not require me throwing my card away?? I can't really do that.

Comment: This is meant as a test , if i am right (hopefully not) your card is in an irreversible read-only mode forever.